# Numpy loadtxt returns empty array

Tags: python, numpy

I am having trouble loading a text file with np.loadtxt()

The file is about 8KB of DNA sequence, in a single line. I am using Python 3 in Spyder. When I try

```
dna = np.loadtxt('dataset_3_2.txt', dtype='str', delimiter='\n')
dna[0]
```

I would get an error saying `too many indices for array`. Under the variable explorer window I can see the size is `()`, similarly when I do `dna.shape`.

However if I add anything in the second line, such as

```
TGACTAGC.....TACGA
blah blah
```

`dna.shape` will return `(2,)` and I can access the data using `dna[0]`, while `dna[1]` will return `blah`

Why doesn't the first file return an array size of `(1,)`, and how do I load a single line of string using `loadtxt()`?

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the dataset?

Comment: It is a randomly generated plain text file that is like `CACACAGGCTGGTAC....ACCAACAGCACTTGTTCCAAA`, and everything is in a single line

Comment: *"The file is about 8KB of DNA sequence, in a single line."*   You don't need `np.loadtxt` to read such a file. You could use  `with open('dataset_3_2.txt', 'r') as f: data = f.read().rstrip()` to put the data into a string.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser your method works perfectly, but I'm still curious why it only loads correctly when there are two lines instead of one

Comment: You probably want to drop `delimiter="\n"` as your file likely does not have a trailing newline.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko the `delimiter='\n'` was added to test the 2 line input file. When removed, it still does not work for the one line input file

Comment: `dna[0]` gave `IndexError: too many indices for array` because when the file has just one line, and there is just one big field (of 8K characters), the array that `np.loadtxt` creates has shape `()`;  that is, it is a zero-dimensional array.  So `dna[0]` fails because there is no value with index 0.

Comment: You can avoid that error by adding the argument `ndmin=1` to your `np.loadtxt` call.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `ndmin=1` fixed the issue. Regarding to the original issue, if I do `print(dna)`, I can see the data, but how do I access? The data is loaded somewhere, but since I cannot index into it, how and where is the data itself?

Comment: One way to get a Python string out of that 0-d array (also know as a "scalar array") is `dna.item()`.